# simplexml_load_file() with proxy server ? how?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, simplexml

I try to implement in php the following code together with using proxies:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file('http://www.testdomain.com/data/search?q='.
                             urlencode($searchstring).'&format=xml');
```

How can i modify this code so that the URL is fetched via a proxy server?
I found some examples, but they all use cURL and i dont exactly know how to implement it.

Any help would be appreciated !

Annotation:
would it work like this?

```
$url = "http://www.testdomain.com/data/search?q='.urlencode($searchstring).'&format=xml";
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) 
        AppleWebKit/532.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
        Chrome/4.0.233.0 Safari/532.4";

$referer = "http://www.google.com/";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '202.95.141.129:8080');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

$curldata = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$data = simplexml_load_string($curldata);
```

?

Comment: http://php.net/simplexml_load_file - there is a stream-context that allows you to specify the proxy server: http://php.net/libxml_set_streams_context - proxy (and other) stream context options for HTTP: http://php.net/context.http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the file via cURL and load the content in simplexml_load_string.

Comment: thanks! i changed my original post - would it work like in my example?

Comment: Excepting the typo error in line 1, it should.
Haven't you tested it?

Comment: sorry, cant test it on this computer right now, have to wait till tonight... what typo?

Comment: Okay.
First Line: `$url = "http://www.testdomain.com/data/search?q=".urlencode($searchstring)."&format=xml";` instead of `$url = "http://www.testdomain.com/data/search?q='.urlencode($searchstring).'&format=xml";`

Answer (score 0):

This is some sample code. It work for me:

```
$context = array(
  'http' => array(
    'proxy' => 'proxy.domain:3128',
    'request_fulluri' => true,
  ),
);
$cxContext = stream_context_create($context);
$sFile = file_get_contents("http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml", False, $cxContext);
$xml = simplexml_load_string ( $sFile."" );
```